# How to call the preview version of Azure OCR in Python?

Tags: python, azure, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

Azure  Cognitive Services OCR has  a demo on the site
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/#text

On the website, I get pretty accurate results. However, when I try to call the same using the code mentioned in their documentation, I get different and poor results.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts/python-print-text

I'm assuming, the version available on the site is the preview one.
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200

How can I call that version in Python?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

There is now an official Microsoft package for that:

- https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision/

With samples:

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-python-sdk-samples/blob/master/samples/vision/computer_vision_samples.py

Create issue on Github if you have troubles :)

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

(I work at MS in the Azure SDK team, which releases this SDK)

Answer (score 0):

There are two different APIs for recognizing text.  The demo page is using the new way, but has the caveat that it only works for English as of this writing.

The example code you should be looking at is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts/python-hand-text).  If you want to recognized printed text, you will tweak the `param`.  It'll look something like this:

```
region = 'westcentralus'
request_url = 'https://{region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/recognizeText'.format(region=region)
headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key}
params  = {'mode': 'Printed'}
data    = {'url': image_url}
response = requests.post(
    request_url, headers=headers, params=params, json=data)
```

You will normally get a HTTP 202 response, not the recognition result.  You will need to fetch the response from the operation location:

```
operation_url = response.headers["Operation-Location"]
operation_response = requests.get(operation_url, headers=headers)
```

Note that you'll need to check the status of the `operation_response` to make sure the task has completed:

```
if operation_response.json()[u'status'] == 'Succeeded': ...
```